# Update multiple properties in Realm without touching the other (saved) values

Tags: swift, realm

When reading the [docs](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/), it says I should do the following to update a single (or multiple) field through a dictionary:

```
var person = ["personID": "My-Primary-Key", "name": "Tom Anglade"]

// Update `person` if it already exists, add it if not.
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true)
}
```

I have no idea how they can get to compile, because I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'Object'
```

I want to dynamically update multiple field throughout a dictionary, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that tutorial is correct, even though it's from the official website written by Realm engineers. If you look at the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/3.1.1/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm3adduRxs8SequenceWx8Iterator7Element_CS_6ObjectrFTx6updateSb_T_) of RealmSwift, you can see that both versions of the `add` function accept an argument subclassing `Object`.

The function you are looking for and that should be mentioned in the tutorial is `public func create<T: Object>(_ type: T.Type, value: Any = [:], update: Bool = false) -> T`, which you can use to update an existing object from a `Dictionary`.

Your code should look like:

```
var person = ["personID": "My-Primary-Key", "name": "Tom Anglade"]

// Update `person` if it already exists, add it if not.
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(Person.self, value: person, update: true)
}
```